# Can't submit callble objects that return void to a thread pool, but only callable objects that returns values

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, threadpool, std

I'm working on a thread pool from the book [C++ Cuncerrency in Action by Anthony Willimas](http://www.manning.com/williams/)
This thread pools has a submit call that take as tasks callable objects that return a value and return a `std::future` handle to them, and I managed to build applications that use it.
But I can't manage to make it work with callable ojects that return void: the code won't even compile. I get these errors, all in the `future` header :

```
error C2182: '_Get_value' : illegal use of type 'void'  
error C2182: '_Val' : illegal use of type 'void'    
error C2182: '_Val' : illegal use of type 'void'    
error C2665: 'std::forward' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types  
error C2512: 'std::_Promise<int>' : no appropriate default constructor available
```

The `submit` call is

```
    template<typename FunctionType>
    std::future<typename std::result_of<FunctionType()>::type> submit(FunctionType f){
        typedef typename std::result_of<FunctionType()>::type result_type;
        std::packaged_task<result_type()> task(std::move(f));
        std::future<result_type> res(task.get_future());
        work_queue.push(std::move(task));
        return res;
    }
```

If I comment this line

```
work_queue.push(std::move(task));
```

the code compiles. So I think that the problem is "there"...

The `work_queue` is delcared as

```
threadsafe_queue<function_wrapper> work_queue;
```

where `threadsafe_queue` is

```
template<typename T>
class threadsafe_queue{
private:
    mutable std::mutex mut;
    std::queue<std::shared_ptr<T> > data_queue;
    std::condition_variable data_cond;
public:
    threadsafe_queue(){}

    void push(T new_value){
        std::shared_ptr<T> data(
        std::make_shared<T>(std::move(new_value)));
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
        data_queue.push(data);
        data_cond.notify_one();
    }

                 //[...]
}
```

and `threadsafe_queue`

```
class function_wrapper{

    struct impl_base {
        virtual void call()=0;
        virtual ~impl_base() {}
    };

    std::unique_ptr<impl_base> impl;

    template<typename F>
    struct impl_type: impl_base{
        F f;
        impl_type(F&& f_): f(std::move(f_)) {}
        void call() { f(); }
    };

public:
    template<typename F>
    function_wrapper(F&& f):impl(new impl_type<F>(std::move(f))){}
    void operator()() { impl->call(); }

    function_wrapper(){}
    function_wrapper(function_wrapper&& other):impl(std::move(other.impl)){}
    function_wrapper& operator=(function_wrapper&& other){
        impl=std::move(other.impl);
        return *this;
    }

private:
    function_wrapper(const function_wrapper&);
    function_wrapper(function_wrapper&);
    function_wrapper& operator=(const function_wrapper&);
};
```

I tried with, but I got the same errors.

```
    template<typename FunctionType>
    std::future<void> submit(FunctionType f){
        std::packaged_task<void(void)> task(std::move(f));
        std::future<void> res(task.get_future());
        work_queue.push(std::move(task));
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: what is the point of `function_wrapper`?  It looks like a half done `std::function<void()>` clone.

Comment: @Yakk it is there because std::function<> requires
that the stored function objects are copy-constructible, while std::packaged_task<> is just movable, not copyable.

Comment: @darius - I have implemented this same thread pool and have used it a few times. Are you still looking for an answer?

Comment: I have a working version that works with `packaged_task<void(void)>`as you desire.

Comment: @CharlesPehlivanian Yes, that would be perfect! Thank you, and sorry for my late reply, I've been away and without internet.

Comment: I hate to say it but this is one thing that only Windows got right: ONLY the OS can properly provide a thread pool implementation - only the OS can know what other processes are doing and whether there are too many threads running on the whole machine. The OS also knows when threads get blocked on I/O. What's going to happen when you have multiple CPU-intensive programs that all create a 16-thread thread pool on a 16-processor machine? You have a massive over-subscription that thrashes the caches. Maybe one day when there are 100+ busy threads on a linux box the linux community will wake up.