# std::move of std::packaged_task<void()> does not compile (vs2013)

Tags: concurrency, stdthread

`std::move` doe's not compile when moving an `std::packaged_task<void()>` object.

the errors are:

error C2182: '_Get_value' : illegal use of type 'void'
error C2182: '_Val' : illegal use of type 'void'
error C2182: '_Val' : illegal use of type 'void'
error C2665: 'std::forward': none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
error C2512: 'std::_Promise': no appropriate default constructor available

The code is:

```
struct CalcFib
{
    int m_num;
    int m_res;
    CalcFib(int number) :m_num(number)
    {

    }

    CalcFib() :m_num(0)
    {

    }

    void  operator()()
    {
        m_res = fib(m_num);
    }

    int fib(int num)
    {
        if (num < 2) return num;
        else return fib(num - 1) + fib(num - 2);
    }

};

std::packaged_task<void()> task(std::move(CalcFib(30)));

std::packaged_task<void()> task1 = std::move(task);
```

This code is successfully compiled:

```
struct CalcFib
{
    int m_num;
    int m_res;
    CalcFib(int number) :m_num(number)
    {

    }

    CalcFib() :m_num(0)
    {

    }

    int  operator()()
    {
        m_res = fib(m_num);
        return m_res;
    }

    int fib(int num)
    {
        if (num < 2) return num;
        else return fib(num - 1) + fib(num - 2);
    }

};

std::packaged_task<int()> task(std::move(CalcFib(30)));

std::packaged_task<int()> task1 = std::move(task);
```

[similar issue was asked here but has not answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915316/cant-submit-callble-objects-that-return-void-to-a-thread-pool-but-only-callabl)

Comment: Can you add compiler version and system? This compiles fine with clang 3.4.1 (`-std=c++11`) and gcc 4.8.5.

Comment: Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.40629 for x86

Comment: This is a bug of visual studio compiler, fount a nice solution [here][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744588/why-is-stdpackaged-taskvoid-not-valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is visual studio compiler bug, I found a nice solution by implementing packaged_task [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744588/why-is-stdpackaged-taskvoid-not-valid)